# Angular NG-Model not setting

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to set the NG-Model on an input box (within a form if that matters) but it doesn't seem like it ever gets set on $scope. Everytime I set a breakpoint on the if statement in the controller 'lpScan' is always blank. I've tried to display the {{lpScan}} on screen and it also never seems like it sets there. Anybody have any ideas on why that might be?

Here is the small piece of controller code:

```
        $scope.submitLP = function () {

        $scope.lpScan = "";

        if (!$scope.checkInForm.$valid) {
            $scope.formValidate = 1;
            return;
        }


        if ($scope.scanRequired && $scope.lpScan !== $scope.lp.LPNumber) {
            FoundationApi.publish('load-notification',
                {
                    title: 'Invalid LP',
                    content: 'Must scan current LP to receive it.',
                    autoclose: '4000'
                });
        }
```

and here is the html

```
<div class="full-block">
        <form name="checkInForm">
            <div class="center data-item">
                <div class="button" ng-click="reprintLP()">Reprint LP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="data-item" ng-if="scanRequired && !lp.CheckedIn"
            </div>
            <div class="data-label-narrow">Scan LP:</div>
            <div class="data-wide"><input id="assignLP" autocomplete="off" type="tel"
                                          ng-keypress="processKeystroke(event)"
                                          ng-model="lpScan" placeholder="Scan LP" name="LPNumber"
                                          required ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" ng-minlength="20" ng-maxlength="20"
                                          ng-trim="true"/>
                <div class="data-error"
                     ng-if="(checkInForm.LPNumber.$dirty || formValidate === 1) && checkInForm.LPNumber.$invalid">
                    LPNumber must be 20 digits
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: did you add the corresponding ngController directive in the html?

Comment: Yes everything is working in the controller. Everything except the model being set.

Comment: What I meant to ask is if you added the ng-controller directive IN the html, for instance <div class="full-block" ng-controller="yourController">

Comment: It looks like it had something to do with ng-minlength="20". Does the model not get set until the length of the field is 20? when this piece was removed I could see the model being set. Also I set the ng-model to $parent.lpScan. I'm guessing that had to do with the field being within a form?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a broken div in your example code HTML.

`<div class="data-item" ng-if="scanRequired && !lp.CheckedIn"`

Try adding `ng-change` on your `input` something like `ng-change="watchInput()"` then in your controller add

```
$scope.watchInput = function() {
    console.log($scope.lpScan);
}
```

Check your console log and see if you are getting a logging at all. If it is then just place your actionable code inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are resetting your $scope.lpScan variable to blank everytime your submitLP function is fired, so declare it outside your submit function:

```
$scope.lpScan = "";
$scope.submitLP = function () {...
```

Here is an example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/jcLsGoVFCXkmv1SnUdHl?p=preview